# Force F() expression to return a model instance rather than a primary key

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

[image]

In the documentation, is there a way to override this behavior?

i.e. I want `car.built_by` to return a model instance i.e. `<Manufacturer: Toyota>` rather than a primary key since I need to maintain the foreign key relationship while annotating.

**Update:**

I'm currently developing a basketball stats website. I have the following models:

```
# models.py

class Game(models.Model):
    league = models.ForeignKey('League', ...)
    tournament = models.ForeignKey('Tournament', ...)
    home_team = models.ForeignKey('Team',...)
    away_team = models.ForeignKey('Team',...)
    home_pts = models.IntegerField()
    away_pts = models.IntegerField()

class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField()
    team_code = models.CharField()
    team_nickname = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.team_name} {self.team_nickname}'
```

I'm using django-tables2 to populate the table of a Team's schedule for a particular tournament. So I do the following query:

```
Game.objects.filter(tournament_id=/insert_tournament_id_here/).filter(Q(home_team_id=self.id) | Q(away_team_id=self.id))
```

that gives me the Games of the Team. My problem is that when I'm populating the views.py of the team schedule, I want it to be "Opponent" rather than "Home Team" and "Away Team". So I decided to do this:

```
Team_Game_Queryset.annotate(opponent=Case(When(home_team=/team_id/, then=F('away_team')), default=F('home_team'), output_field=ForeignKey('myapp.Team'))
```

my problem is that, the annotated column "opponent" isn't a ForeignKey reference for the Team model, so I can't use the str representation of the object. I was able to do this by converting the QuerySet into a pandas DataFrame and then returning a dictionary (which is an easy read into django-tables2). But I always prefer to return a QuerySet to django-tables rather than a dict, and I was wondering if there was any way to overwrite the F() behavior, or if there's any other way to do this using QuerySets.

Comment: Code belongs in your question, not as an image.

Comment: What do you mean? sorry I don't frequently ask SO questions since I often find what I'm looking for just scouring SO questions. In this particular instance, I couldn't find one after a few days.

Comment: I dont think that it is possible with F() to have a object.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use F here at all.

Comment: F operates at a db level. You can't have Python objects in the db. Maybe your real problem does not need you to annotate a foreign key.

Comment: @ResleyRodrigues I'd prefer to do it using a QuerySet rather than to convert the QuerySet into a dataframe using django-pandas. 

Let me update my question to include my real problem. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've said you're using django-tables2, I'm assuming you have a table class

```
# tables.py
import django_tables2 as tables

class Game Table(tables.Table):
    opponent = tables.Column()

    class Meta:
        model = Game

    def __init__(self, team_id, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def render_opponent(self, record):
        return record.home_team if record.away_team_id == self.team_id else record.away_team

# views.py
def list_team_games(request):
    query_set = Game.objects.filter(tournament_id=/insert_tournament_id_here/).filter(Q(home_team_id=self.id) | Q(away_team_id=self.id))
    table = GameTable(self.id, queryset)

    return render(request, 'game_list.html', {
        'table': table
    })
```

Note that I have added a `opponent` column and written a `render_opponent` method on the table. ([Refer to the docs](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html#table-render-foo-methods))

I personally have never used django-tables2, but this is what I put together by reading the tutorial in the documentation

Comment: I've also tried doing that before and I couldn't get it to work. 
the only difference between your code and what I did was I had a Team instance in the view so I just passed `Team.id` instead of `self.id`

Comment: I finally figured out what was wrong using this approach:

i assigned `self.team_id = team_id` after `super()` when I should have done it before. It's completely working now. Thanks so much for the push in the right direction!

Comment: Happy to help! You could mark this as the answer if it helped (and might help someone else some day)